# "Der gute Mann" vs. "Ein guter Mann"

Tags: definite-article

Wie nennt man die Konstruktion im Deutschen, wenn das Adjektiv eine andere Endung hat, wenn der Artikel definitiv bzw. nicht definitiv ist? Warum betrachtet man das nicht als anderen Kasus?

> *"der gute Mann"* vs. *"ein guter Mann"* (beides Nominativ?)
>   *"dem guten Manne"* vs. *"einem guten Manne"* (beides Dativ und dieselbe Endung)
>   *"mein guter Mann"* (wie *"ein guter Mann"*, aber nicht wie *"der gute Mann"*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das nennt man *starke, gemischte* bzw. *schwache Deklination* des Adjektivs.

Dass das Ganze nicht als anderer Kasus betrachtet wird, liegt daran, dass der Unterschied satzglied-intern ist und nichts mit der Funktion des entsprechenden Satzgliedes zu tun hat – genauso gut könnte man grammatikalische Geschlechter als eigenen Kasus zu betrachten. Die Unsinnigkeit der getrennten Kasus wird auch ersichtlich, wenn man beide Deklinationen in einem Satzglied auftauchen lässt: *Der gute Mann und ein böser Hund gingen über die Straße.*

Comment: +1. Aber was ist der Ursprung dieser Änderung? Hat es damit zu tun, dass man keine Information widerholen will? z.B. In „ein guter Mann”  enthüllt der Artikel das Geschlecht des Substantivs nicht. In Gegenteil, ein bestimmter Artikel macht es und „der guter Mann” würde Wiederholung.

Comment: @c.p. Das ist eine sehr gute Frage und auch eine sinnvolle Vermutung. Ich kann dazu nichts sagen, aber es sollte nicht in Form eines Kommentars untergehen...

Comment: Ich kann jemanden mit "guter Mann" ansprechen, aber nicht mit "gute Mann". Der Unterschied ist also nicht satzgliedintern. Es handelt sich um zwei Faelle, die beide Subjekt sein koennen, aber nur einer kann wie ein Vokativ verwendet werden.

Comment: @Andrew J. Brehm: Da habe ich mehrere Einwände: Erstens können sehr wohl unterschiedlich Adjektiv-Formen als Vokativ verwendet werden, z. B.: *liebe Leute* und *ihr lieben Leute.* Da sich die standardsprachlichen Vokativ-Phrasen an einer Hand abzählen lassen, überrascht es auch nicht, dass sie nur eine Form enthalten, insbesondere angesichts der Natur des Vokativs. Umgangssprachlich ist es schon anders: *Der gute Mann dort, kommen Sie mal her!* Schließlich muss man dem Vokativ, wenn man ihn als eigenen Fall einstuft, auch eigene Formen zugestehen, die schlichtweg identisch sein können.

Comment: Die Theorie der Vermeidung wiederholter Information ist natürlich nicht 100%ig stichhaltig: "Der gute Mann, die gute Frau, das gute Kind", aber "ein guter Mann, eine gute Frau, ein gutes Kind". Wie man sieht, wird bei schwacher Deklination (mit best. Artikel o.ä.) das Genus nicht erkennbar, bei der starken wird es wiederholt, obwohl auch im (unbestimmten) Artikel erkennbar.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  Ich verstehe nicht ganz, was du meinst: bei der starken Deklination sind die Artikel gleich für Männlich und Neutrum, sodass man daraus doch nicht das Genus erkennen kann.

Comment: @TaraB Ich dachte, es geht hier nicht um die Artikel, sondern die Adjektive.

Comment: Wenn es darum geht, ob Information wiederholt wird, dann geht es um die Artikel _und_ die Adjektive.

Comment: Akkusativ: einen guten Mann, den guten Mann. In beiden Fällen wird einem die Info, dass Mann maennlich ist, zweimal verraten; eine Wiederholung wird also nicht vermieden.

Answer (score 1):

> Warum betrachtet man das nicht als anderen Kasus?

Man könnte dass tun, aber der Begriff "Fall" wurde so bestimmt, dass er unabhängig von Artikel ist :)

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasus

Außerdem, muss man sich erinnern dass die Fälle der deutschen Sprache, aus den Fällen der urgermanischen Sprache abgeleitet wurden.
Wer weiß, vielleicht waren die Formen dieser Urkasus miteinander ähnicher als die, der heutigen Kasus.
Vielleicht hat deine Frage für die Urgermanen eine offensichtliche Antwort - aber ich bin nicht so fleißig danach zu suchen

Answer (score 0):

Die Endungen -er/-es, die Aufschluß über das Geschlecht geben, werden nur einmal gesetzt. Wenn das Artikelwort (der, dieser, welcher etc) die Genusendung -er/-es hat, wird diese Endung nicht noch einmal beim Addjektiv wiederholt, das wäre redundant.

Nur bei Artikelwörtern, die die Genusendung abgeworfen haben (ein, mein etc) bekommt das Adjektiv die Genusendung. Oder wenn kein Artikelwort benützt wird.

Dieses System ist für Deutschlernende etwas kompliziert, zugegeben. Noch dazu ist das in Grammatiken mit Regeln erklärt, ohne das Warum ausreichend zu erklären.